# Where can I find a Portal Gem, and how does it work?

Tags: path-of-exile

Earlier today I've seen a guy selling a [Portal Gem](http://en.pathofexilewiki.com/wiki/Portal).  Never heard of that before.  from what I've read so far, it seems pretty rare and expensive.  Is it possible to find it anywhere (on any difficulty) ?

[image: Portal gem]

Also, this gem is white.  Does it mean it will fit any slot color ?  And I suppose it requires to bind a key to use it ?

Comment: From what I understand, you can get one at level 1. It's all rng.  I have no proof though, just what I've heard and read in GGG forums.  I got mine in Cruel Western Forest runs.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Portal gem is the only unique gem in the game, and, you guessed it, it opens a town portal =)

***The upside:*** *Never have to use a TP scroll again*! You can save them and trade them for ID scrolls!  Fits in any color slot.  And you don't really need to "bind a key"...  You can just place it on one of the keys when you need it, or put it on your secondary weapons. (that's what I do)

***The downside:*** *It has a cast time.*  At 20% increased quailty, it becomes 40% decreased cast time.

And yes, they are quite rare.

Sources: I have one, [wiki](http://en.pathofexilewiki.com/wiki/Portal)

Alas, I died, so no longer have my precious Portal Gem.

Comment: Empower, Enlighten & Enhance are considered unique as well, AFAIK :)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, they are quite rare drop which you can get from almost any monster in any area of any difficulty.

The gem can be put in any socket, no matter the color. And yes, if you want to use it you have to put it under skill slot (if you already use all of them, then just replace one of the skill with teleport when you'll need to use it and bring back the skill to that slot once you're done teleporting).

It's also worth noting that the portal doesn't open instantly like when using portal scroll, it takes 2.5 seconds (lesser if it's quality gem) to open the portal when using the gem so it's not recommended that you try to use it as an emergency escape as it might get you killed.